# Nginx - 502 bad gateway

Tags: server, nginx

I'm working through [How To Serve Django Applications with uWSGI and Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04).

I have completed the tut and restarted both nginx and uwsgi. I notice that if I go to the IP of my server, I see my site (making me think that uwsgi is working properly). However if I go to `www.mysite.com`, I get the 502 error. My nginx config file in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available` is `mysite` contains:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/deploy/mysite;
}

location / {
    include         uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/mysite.sock;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
$ systemctl status uwsgi
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

I'm confused, I know I have been working on a number of uwsgi files and

```
$ sudo systemctl start uwsgi
```

does not cause an error. Also the website is still being served at the IP address. I thought uwsgi was doing that.

```
$ netstat -a|grep uwsgi
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2373238691 /run/uwsgi/mysite.sock
```

Comment: Check in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` you might get the error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The 502 Bad Gateway error means server is not getting proper response from another server. In your case it is `uWSGI` server. It is either not running or stopped due to error.

Check the status of uWSGI server by using `sudo systemctl status uwsgi`.

Answer (score 2):

In php7 www-conf is in: `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d`

In this file I find this:

```
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock

; Set listen(2) backlog.
```

I set a parameter in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/[site]`

```
upstream php-handler {
    #server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    server unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

And it's working :)

Comment: For me it was `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;` like you said, this comes from php-fpm, which would not accept a configuration change to `127.0.0.1:9000`